# PhalconPHP re-query/filter result

Tags: php, sql, phalcon

In PhalconPHP i make some query like:

```
$result = Model::callSomeModelFunction($param);
```

How could $result be re-queried, is something alike possible? :

```
$result = $result->filterOnceMoreWithNewParam($anotherParam);
```

Or would I have to use this in the first line :

```
$result = Model::callSomeOtherModelFunction($param, $anotherParam);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If callSomeModelFunction returns a result set, e.g. (Model::find('deleted = N') then you can use ->filter

From Docs on [resultsets](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Resultset.html):

```
$filtered = $result->filter(function($individualRecord){
    if ($individualRecord->id < 3) {
        return $individualRecord;
    }
});
```

Now $filtered will be a resultset narrowed down by the filter inside of the if block.